# Mobile resizing issue with all elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am working on taking my desktop site and scaling it down for mobile.  The site is incredibly static, so the process shouldn't take long.  I'm not used to scaling down to mobile though, so I am in a bit of a learning curve and was seeking some help.  I have my menu in place where the mobile menu displays and the desktop menu hides when the screen is sized down:

```
@media (min-width: 220px) and (max-width: 568px) {
#menu ul, #logo, #header{
  display: none;
}
```

vice-versa goes for when the desktop is in place and it hides the mobile nav:

```
@media (min-width: 569px) {
.navbar{
  display: none;
   }
}
```

However, when I am tweaking my CSS to alter my mobile view, my first run-in is with simply just displaying my content (in this case my 'about' content) to fit the screen.  My fluidity in desktop isn't ideal, but it works as needed on all displays from tablets and beyond.  I bare-boned the About page to just have my text and a horizontal break being displayed in order to troubleshoot the issue, but the text still follows the rules set by the CSS for the desktop version.  Here is the @media rule to size for mobile:

```
@media (min-width: 220px) and (max-width: 568px) {
#menu ul, #logo, #header{
  display: none;
}
  .about_text{
    width: 100%;
  }

.about_text h2{
  font-size: 3em;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}
.breaker-about{
  clear: both;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #cccccc;
  margin: 5px 0px 12px 0px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

}

```
@media (min-width: 569px) {
.navbar{
  display: none;
   }
}
```

Do I need to encompass the entire CSS in the @media (min-width: 569px) media query from here on out?  Or does that act as a single standalone 'if/then' rule?

Here's my fiddle.  Using bootstrap for top nav, so that's why the resize down to size doesn't stylize on fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/qu4851wq/1/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `(min-width: 220px)` for mobile, just the `(max-width: 568)` is enough. If you're using Bootstrap, you can just put your entire contents into a grid and it will automatically scale for mobile.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- All your content after the nav -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't have to place the entirety of your CSS in a `min-width` for the non-mobile portion of the site.

Comment: Would this in turn have me make a second html file for each page that each uses bootstrap's mobile resizing for the content?

Comment: Bootstrap is just a stylesheet that makes your life very simple. Every site that you have, you can place the content the grid. Furthermore, you don't need to hide your navigation at all. Bootstrap creates the responsive navigation and hides the rest on desktop. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid will explain the grid better.

It's not good practice to hide your content on mobile - you should be able to have a fully functioning website that shows all your content no matter the size. Bootstrap will take care of the styling for you. 

You will need to load the Bootstrap jQuery as well for the nav.

Comment: I really do like what bootstrap can do, but I really just want to use it for the header and any kind of content I can with minimum alterations to my current desktop content.  I would essentially have to rebuild my site using BS if I were to go about using it this way =/

Comment: Not really. Did you try putting the content in the three divs as I suggested?

Comment: Yeah, if I replace my tags and just place the markup itself inside it works just fine.  But with that being the case, it would show no stylng for desktop since my tags would no longer be there - just the ones provided by bootstrap.

What I need is the completed desktop version with my custom styling (works fine now) and the break point bootstrap mobile format for mobile.  I just can't figure out, after reading the API, how I can do this without just creating a second mobile version of the site.

Comment: You can put it in the grid, and style it accordingly. The whole point of Bootstrap is to customize the site the way you want, while not having to create two websites. Place your content in the divs, then add your custom styling on top of that. (Your style sheet will go after the Bootstrap one).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use bootstrap default navigation and style it like you want.

[bootstrap nav](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)